# Difference between modifying /etc/hosts vs using dnsmasq service

Tags: networking, dnsmasq

After reading the man pages of `dnsmasq` it seems either way it checks `/etc/hosts` so what exactly is the difference between adding IP: domain names in `/etc/hosts` and doing the same plus run `dnsmasq` on top?

Answer (score 0):

I use dnsmasq in my lab to serve DHCP and provide DNS to attached devices. /etc/hosts does neither.  In addition, DNS of outside lookups is faster due to caching.

Comment: Is caching of addresses not done by default on every machine?

Comment: There does not have to be a central service.  Browsers do their own lookups and caching, for example.

Comment: Yes, so far caching no need for dnsmasq, is this what you're saying?

Comment: /etc/hosts on the dnsmasq server will be served to any clients

Comment: @Jasen and if it's just a single computer?

Comment: if it's a single computer then softwares that don't check /etc/hosts  will see the content under dnsmasq

Answer (score 0):

A name service - DNS - is required on an IP network, to maintain names that mean something. Even when IP addresses change.

Networks are going to have many hosts, and they all need to resolve these names. Names in a file implies copying /etc/hosts around, which has not scaled well for many decades. And in modern times, features like DNS64 or running in the cloud or non-POSIX hosts are even less suited for a static file. The vast majority of networks should be running DNS.

dnsmasq able to refer to /etc/hosts is an implementation quirk of that software. Somewhat like the zone file format is a quirk of BIND and other DNS software.  Although you can configure hosts to use the former in their resolver, you should not.